# Why is this alertView code not working? No error, just not doing as it should

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"buttonindex: %i", buttonIndex);
    NSLog(@"tag: %i", alertView.tag);
    if ((alertView.tag <= 3) && (alertView.tag >= 1)) {

    } //Between 1 and 3
    else if (alertView.tag = 8) {

        }
    else if (alertView.tag = 10) {
        NSLog(@"Test");

    }
}
```

For some reason, even though i'm using alertView with tag 10, and it's returning "Tag: 10" on the NSLog, it isn't showing the "Test" log, or processing any code from within those last brackets. And yet alertView tag 8 is working fine.

Comment: check for the usage of the tag [xcode]: stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be careful, it should be == in your if statements. Apart from that, how do you assign tags to the alertviews?

Comment: just to add to this... alertview tag 8 is working fine because using a single `=` in your if statements means that your code reads "if the tag ISN'T 2 then set the alertView.tag to 8 (which will return true because its completed successfully) and then it runs the bit for =8". So as long as the first if query isn't true then the second one WILL always be true.

Comment: Almost. The assignment evaluates to true because the value of the left-hand side of the expression is non-zero after the assignment.

Comment: lol... yes, I understand - its the same reason why `echo $var = "hello";` works in php I'm guessing.

Comment: I see! And can't believe i missed that. Thanks.

Comment: In languages that allow assignment it is recommended to put the literals first `if(8 = alertView.tag)` would have nicely given you an error